# Blender glft mirrors armature after exporting model

Tags: blender, gltf

I have gltf model with rig and animation sequences (with .bin), exported from video game League of Legends. After mport into Blender, everything looks fine (almost, but that's not important for rig), but after exporting into other format (I export as .smd to use in Source Filmmaker, but also tried othe formats) and importing into Blender exported model armature mirrors along global Y. Here's how animation has to look [image: here's how animation has to look]
And here is what comes after export-import:
import mesh with armature, but without animation [image: import mesh with armature, but without animation]
and what comes with adding animation [image: what comes with adding animation]
(for this after previous screenshot I flipped mesh in edit mode along Y global).

I tried to mirror before/after export-import both armature and mesh. Nothing helped before. On last screenshot everything is flipped along global X. One day I fixed it, but her weapon (circle thing) is always behind her after export-import when it must be ahead of her.